# Handling delegate with out parameter

Tags: c#, anonymous-methods

I've got an delegate and event with an out parameter:

> public delegate void ExampleDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e, out string value);
>
> public event ExampleDelegate Example;

When I'm trying to handle the event:

```
 mg.Example += (sender, e, val) =>
 {
    //do stuff
 };
```

I'm getting the error *Parameter 3 must be declared with the 'out' keyword*

When I'm throwing in the suggested out keyword like so:

```
 mg.Example += (sender, e, out val) =>
 {
    //do stuff
 };
```

I'm getting and extra error *the type of namespace name 'val' could not be found..etc*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're breaking the event handler design. Create your own EventArgs class instead.

Comment: @AmiramKorach your answer is the one I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event handler doesn't confirm to the .net guidelines.

If you must use it like that, use a delegate, not an event.

You would run into trouble if you had two event handlers modifying your out parameter.

Refer: [Events Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> .NET Framework Guidelines
>
> Although the C# language allows events to use any delegate type, the
>   .NET Framework has some stricter guidelines on the delegate types that
>   should be used for events. If you intend for your component to be used
>   with the .NET Framework, you probably will want to follow these
>   guidelines.
>
> The .NET Framework guidelines indicate that the delegate type used for
>   an event should take two parameters, an "object source" parameter
>   indicating the source of the event, and an "e" parameter that
>   encapsulates any additional information about the event. The type of
>   the "e" parameter should derive from the EventArgs class. For events
>   that do not use any additional information, the .NET Framework has
>   already defined an appropriate delegate type: EventHandler.

zmbq has already given you the answer to how to correct your error.

*I am adding this just for completeness.*

Answer (score 4):

Well, as it clearly says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990569/write-a-lambda-or-anonymous-function-that-accepts-an-out-parameter), you need to specify the type of `val`:

```
(sender, e, out string val)=> ...
```

Comment: A note on that answer you link to says that you need to specify types for *all* parameters.